# Google Material Color or Own Color?

Tags: android, ios

I am programming an Android App, and a Friend of mine does the same for iOS. Now I have to choose a Color, but I am not sure, if I should take one of the Material Design colors, or if we should choose one on our own.
The advantage of the Google provided colors are, that they fit very good to the whole design, but I am afraid, that the recognition value of our App is compromised.
Also on iOS the Material Design Colors doesn't really fit, so we probably would have two different colors. Do you think this is a Problem, when we try to build a own brand? I hope this is the correct forum.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on which one has more weight, making sure your brand is recognized by its color, or making sure your app design fit in with the ecosystem design.

Check out this blog by feedly, they discuss how they change some brand color elements to fit into MaterialDesign:

> Google recommends to use the primary color in the toolbars and status bars which usually means using your brand’s color in those areas. Because feedly is a reading app, using our bright green in these bars would be very distracting when your eyes try to focus on content. I chose to use a light grey instead to create a less intrusive toolbar.
>
> On the left drawer I created a toolbar using our brand color to highlight the trending topic of the day. This is a nice way to use our brand’s color to emphasize a key piece of information.

https://medium.com/feedly-behind-the-curtain/an-exploration-in-material-design-by-feedly-8c1a1cbdfdcd